R/RStudio fread() SSL Connect Error: Unable to Read Data from URL Using data.table Package
Unlike my coworker's computer, when I run this code on my machine in RStudio, I encounter an SSL connection error:
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("https://dados.mg.gov.br/dataset/d7840175-2445-4ab3-84eb-ca645f58db31/resource/c57a6e00-a731-442b-81a5-7822b1375130/download/iniciativas_acordo_judicial_reparacao_vale.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")

Error:
Trying the URL 'https://dados.mg.gov.br/dataset/d7840175-2445-4ab3-84eb-ca645f58db31/resource/c57a6e00-a731-442b-81a5-7822b1375130/download/iniciativas_acordo_judicial_reparacao_vale.csv' Error in download.file(file, tmpFile, method = method, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) :  It was not possible to open the URL 'https://dados.mg.gov.br/dataset/d7840175-2445-4ab3-84eb-ca645f58db31/resource/c57a6e00-a731-442b-81a5-7822b1375130/download/iniciativas_acordo_judicial_reparacao_vale.csv' Additionally: Warning message: In download.file(file, tmpFile, method = method, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) : URL 'https://dados.mg.gov.br/dataset/d7840175-2445-4ab3-84eb-ca645f58db31/resource/c57a6e00-a731-442b-81a5-7822b1375130/download/iniciativas_acordo_judicial_reparacao_vale.csv': status was 'SSL connect error'

Could someone please help me?
I couldn’t find any answers that resolved the issue. I came across a similar case here:
fread() error loading csv from https URL on Windows - data.table R 1.9.5 "showProgress must be 1 or 0, currently",
and here:
fread() error loading csv from https URL on Windows - data.table R 1.9.5 "showProgress must be 1 or 0, currently",
but unfortunately, these solutions didn’t work for me either.
